# How can I edit a file if there is no vi, vim, joe, etc?

Tags: linux, shell, text-editors, editing, text-editing

Is there a way to edit a file if there are no vi, vim, joe, mcedit? In another words is there a way to edit a file using just the shell commands?

Comment: You don't even have the `nano` binary on your system?  :S

Comment: I don't have nano, either!

Comment: Its a router, but also I've seen also a custom gateway in this situation :)

Comment: Are you on DD-WRT?

Comment: No, the default firmware

Comment: Make a copy of the file you want to edit. Then do `cat file`, followed by `cat >file` and arrange the parts with cut+paste and/or typing, finish with `ctrl-d`.

Comment: You haven't said if `ed` is present or not...

Comment: This also happened to me, in docker.. It is very minimalistic. Now how the heck do i do something like that. The VM is ephemeral, i cannot ssh nor ftp, i have to use redirection and hacks like sed to change some files. It was a great challenge. See how reliant we are on editors :P

Comment: If this is a container or accessed via some other host you can use `echo <<EOF > new.file [paste here] EOF`. Edit contents of file on host PC.

Comment: this is the case with my Docker image :(

Comment: @codeninja yes you're right. Happened to us too. Great we still have `cat`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In that instance, I'd try transferring files out and editing them on another computer, then transfer them back. If you have ssh, you should have scp (I hope), so you should be able to push files in and out. If not, you can also look for ftp to transfer files in and out.

If not, then I think your best option is to try and make use of cat, grep, sed, echo, and I/O redirection (especially append with `>>`). And lots of temporary files.

Though if you have access to perl (or something similar), you can run it with no arguments and it will let you input a script source from standard input. Once you press ctrl+d, it can then run the script. You could use that method to create a file. It would be more powerful than hacking something on the command line as I mentioned before.

Comment: no sshd but I have telnetd

Comment: Then can you ftp?

Comment: I  can use cat, grep, echo, and I/O redirection (especially append with >>) but no sed

Comment: Well, if you know exactly what you want to write into your file, you should be able to `echo` each line and append it to the end of the file you want. Without `sed`, editing would be a bit difficult, unless you have/know `awk`. Personally, I don't, but it's another alternative to `sed`.

Comment: Ftp works :) now I need to see where on this router do I have something that is writable.

Comment: If you are connected to your device via telnet, I'd seriously think about just catting the file to the terminal (with a sufficiently large backscroll buffer), copy/pasting the entire thing into a local editor, making your changes, and then whipping up something that will turn that into a series of echo commands that will write a replacement file.

Comment: All that will only work for pure text files though.  Binary... not so much.  (Oh, you have ftp?  That makes it easy!)

Comment: @afrazier that is the solution, but found found ftp working

Comment: I'd also look out for `netcat` / `nc` - there's often a very basic version included in `busybox`

Answer (score 25):

Use a terminal that lets you copy and paste with the mouse, and assemble your files that way?

```
e.g.  cat > myfile
(use terminal to copy/paste)
^D
```

If it is a binary file, use this to turn it into text which you can copy with the mouse:

```
 openssl base64 -in <infile>
```

then on another computer, openssl again to decode it using the -d switch, edit however you like (e.g. hexedit) then re-encode, and on the box with no editor, openssl again to decode it and paste from your terminal.
do

Comment: sadly no cursor while booting process is broken, like in grub or initramfs.

Comment: This is an excellent answer ... in many cases like when inside a container where you cannot even install vi ( obviously only during development  )

Comment: You can get KVM devices and USB keyboard emulators and keyboards that can play macros etc etc if you're working on "bare metal", and keep in mind that both HP and Dell (and some other brand) servers do include remote consoles, all of which support sending keys to a console too.

Comment: **This should be the answer.**

Answer (score 10):

One way would to be to output the result of an echo.

```
echo "foo" > bar.txt
```

This will make a file titled bar.yxy with the containing text, "foo".

Comment: That's not really editing.

Comment: Gets the job done, untill you can get an editor on it.

Answer (score 7):

```
cat file.txt
```

copy output and edit content in your regular editor

```
cat <<- "EOF" > file.txt //
// paste edited content
EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're SSH'ing into your router, you can also use various utilities to transfer the file back and fourth to your computer/router.  You can download a copy on your PC, modify it, and then SSH it back to the router via SFTP (see [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) if you're a Windows user).

If you're using a custom firmware on the router/gateway, however, you may be in luck.  There are various Optware packages containing simple (and small) text editors.  Depending on your needs, you could get the `nano` package, or just go for `busybox` which contains `vi`.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you could do what you need with `grep` and `perl` - look for the line you want with `grep`, edit that line with `perl` (`perl` can act like a big replacement for `sed`) and then confirm you didn't make more changes than you intended by doing `diff filename filename.new`. If so, make the changes permanent - `mv filename.new filename`

Answer (score 2):

Install vi - as weird as it sounds, you can often copy an existing "vi" from another machine and it will run OK on your box.  I've found a "/data" partition on a lot of devices where you can save it to, and run it from.

I've done this.  It works.

If you want to improve your chances of getting it working first-try, find any existing executable on your box and run this over it:

```
readelf -h </bin/filename>
```

then check that the "vi" you get form elsewhere uses the same chipset, bitsize, etc.

Works for other programs too (tcpdump is another one I've succeeded with)

Answer (score 2):

I was working on Router with BusyBox installed and it didn't provided any text editor. One of the ways I was able to achieve it was,

1. **Output** the file content using **cat**
2. **Edit** the files on your system/pc
3. **Upload** the updated file on internet such as [Transfer.sh](https://transfer.sh/)
4. **Download the updated file** on the router/device using **curl** command, in my case I had to use the **--ignore** switch as well to bypass certificate/https warning.
5. Remove [**RM**] the old file.
6. Rename/Move [**MV**] the new file with the old files' name.

Answer (score 1):

Did you wipe out /bin or something? Otherwise maybe you could hack something together with the text utilities in the [GNU Coreutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities#Programs_included_in_coreutils) that should be standard on a linux system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl installed, you could give my ed-clone perled a try: https://github.com/nitardus/perled. It is an early beta, more of a challange to implement ed in under 150 lines of pure perl, but perhaps it could be helpful, too...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).